How to write data using WFDB library Record.wrsamp or wfdb.wrsamp functions?
I'm currently working with ECG data using the wfdb library. Loading the data (in the .hea and .dat files) and then writing it back out is proving to be shockingly difficult, not least because the wfdb.rdsamp and wfdb.wrsamp methods are not isomorphic – if you simply read a sample into memory with the default args, you can't write that same sample and in-memory data immediately using the wrsamp method. It doesn't work.
For example:
# WFDB reader and writer do not allow file extensions
input_file = input_file.replace(".hea", "")) 
value = wfdb.rdsamp(input_file)

signal, fields = value

# Do something...

# Write file - by recombining the tuple

value = (signal, fields)
wfdb.wrsamp(value, input_file) # Replace old file


Is there someone with experience working with wfdb in Python that knows of a resource or can provide a working example of how to write and read a file using wfdb.rdsamp and either wfdb.wrsamp or Record.wrsamp?
